# Finding Network Domains Connected in VB.Net

Tags: .net, vb.net, networking

How do I determine which network domain I am connected to from VB.Net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the current domain name, you can use [`Environment.UserDomainName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.userdomainname.aspx) (if the user in whose context the application is running is a domain user).

Alternatively, [`NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties().DomainName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ipglobalproperties.domainname.aspx) will return the domain name independent of the current user (or an empty string, if the PC is not member of a domain).